# Finding Most Recent Value in Table B Relative to Table A's Date

Tags: sql, oracle, date, join, greatest-n-per-group

I currently have two tables: `table a` and `table b`.

[image: Example]
My goal is to take the newest score from `table b` and add it as a new column using a join in `table a` (however when I say "newest" I really mean "latest in relation to `Event_Date` listed in `table a`)

I'm assuming it will be a `left join` but am having trouble pulling the `Score`. All I know how to do is pull the date:

```
select 
a.Entity_ID,
a.Event_Date,
max(b.date_processed) --I want to change this to the score correlated to the max date_processed
from myTable a
left join myTable b
on a.Entity_ID = b.Entity_ID and b.date_processed < a.event_date
Group By a.Entity_ID, a.Event_Date, b.Date_Processed
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want the most recent score from `tabeb`prior to the `event_date` of `tablea`.

One option uses a correlated subquery with a row-limiting clause:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (
        select b.score
        from tableb b
        where b.entity_id = a.entity_id and b.date_processed <= a.event_date
        order by b.date_processed desc
        fetch first 1 row only
    ) most_recent_score
from tablea a
```